# Can't upload theme to Prestashop

Tags: prestashop

So I purchased a prestashop theme from TemplateMonster and the zip file is 324MB and when I try to upload the file in admin, I get an error that the file is too large. I know I can change php settings and maybe get it to work, but I figured I would just ftp it to my server, but filezilla drops the connection when I try to upload it. First, before I change php settings, will it work with such a large file? Also, when I look inside the zip file, I see a .sql file, a psd.zip, readme_en.zip, and 2 other zip files. Do all these files need to be uploaded? Just asking because I'm not sure why the PSD.zip file would need to be included.

413 Request Entity Too Large

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the main theme package contains additional assets, but in order to have your theme installed in Prestashop you just need the "main" ZIP theme
(the one that once unzipped contain folders like **/assets** **/templates** **/modules** etc.)

Then you can choose to upload it from your backoffice (you need to set the PHP *max_upload_filesize* accordingly) or copy the zip directly in your **/themes** directory and choose the "Import with FTP" option for the "*Themes & Logo > Theme > Add new theme*" backoffice page.

If you're having trouble with that method too, you can use the "*Import from the web*"
method by uploading your ZIP in a reachable public URL